# Delete category and its children / grandchildren

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Using ObjectContext. I'm wanting to do this by passing an SQL query via the ExecuteStoreCommand since I don't fancy retrieving all relevant entities just for the sake of deleting them after.

The Category table is as so:

```
CatID | CatName | ParentID
```

Where CatID is the primary key to the ParentID FK

I am wishing to delete a category and also all those that
are under it. Can be 2+ levels deep of sub cats, so different ParentID's

Thought I could do it as below and just set "cascade" on delete option
for the foreign key in the database, but  it won't let me and it does not appear to want to
cascade delete down by using the CatID - ParentID relationship and the query gets
stopped by this very FK constraint.

```
public RedirectToRouteResult DelCat(int CatID)
{
    if (CatID != 0)
    {
        _db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM Categories WHERE CatID={0}", CatID);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("CatManage");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE allCategories produces list of all categories in hierarchy. Delete part, obviously, deletes them all.

```
; with allCategories as (
 select CatID
   from Categories
  where CatID = @CatID_to_delete
  union all
 select Categories.CatID
   from allCategories
  inner join Categories 
     on allCategories.CatID = Categories.ParentID
)
delete Categories
  from Categories 
 inner join allCategories
    on Categories.CatID = allCategories.CatID
```

Try it with `select * from allCategories`, though, to check first.

There is [TEST @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f883f/1).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just send two statements in your batch?

```
DELETE Categories WHERE ParentID = {0};
DELETE Categories WHERE CatID = {0};
```

If the framework you're using "won't let you" do that, then do this right: put your logic in a stored procedure, and call the stored procedure.

Comment: What happens when the categories are three or more levels down. Say: USA>New York>Queens. If I pass this it will delete USA and New York only, since queens ParentID is equal to New York CatID and not the initially passed ParentID. Leaving an orphaned cat. Not that the FK would let me do it anywhere.

Comment: @LaserBeak sorry, you didn't provide any sample data or indicate that there was more than one level. I suggest clarifying the question so that others don't get confused like I did - I assumed a simple category / sub-category model.